# jsoup - stop jsoup from making quotes into &amp;

Tags: jsoup, autoformatting

When I parse local HTML files jsoup changes quotes inside an anchor  element to & obscuring my HTML.

let's assume i want to change the value "one" to "two" in the following HTML part:

```
<div class="pg2-txt1">
  <a class="foo" appareantly_a_javascript_statement='{"targetId":"pg1-magn1", "ordinal":1}'>one</a>
</div>
```

what I get is:

```
<div class="pg2-txt1">
  <a class="foo" appareantly_a_javascript_statement="{&quot;targetId&quot;:&quot;pg1-magn1&quot;, &quot;ordinal&quot;:1}">two</a>
</div>
```

The quotes inside the anchor element are needed. My code looks like this now:

```
File input = new File("D:/javatest/page02.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
Element div = doc.select("div.pg2-txt1").first(); //anchor element only identifyable by parent <div> class
div.child(0).text("one"); //actual anchor element
```

I tried

```
doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
```

with no success.

Can I achieve this with jsoup? Do I have to use a different parser and how would that look like.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [html spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) JSoup behaves totally fine:

> By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using
>   either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation
>   marks (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks can be included within
>   the attribute value when the value is delimited by double quote marks,
>   and vice versa. Authors may also use numeric character references to
>   represent double quotes (") and single quotes ('). For double
>   quotes authors can also use the character entity reference `&quot;`

Note the last sentence!

Basically that means, that your other software that needs the double quotes in the `appareantly_a_javascript_statement` attribute is doing some incomplete parsing of its value.

I see two solutions:

**1) modify the function that interprets the appareantly_a_javascript_statement value**

I can't help you there, since I have no knowledge of where it is done.

**2) Change the Jsoup output via regular expressions.**

This is pretty hacky...

```
String html = doc.outerHtml();
boolean changed = false;
html = html.replaceAll("(=\"\\{)([^\"]+)(\")", "='{$2'");
do{
    int oldLength = html.length();  
    html = html.replaceAll("(=')([^']+)(\\&quot;)([^\']+)(')", "$1$2\"$4$5");
    changed = html.length() != oldLength;
}while(changed);
System.out.print(html);
```